# Solution verification: Proving that a local homeomorphism maps open sets to open sets.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

In an exercise I'm asked to prove the following statement:

> Prove that if $f:(X,\tau) \to (Y,\tau_1)$ is a local homeomorphism, then $f$ maps every open subset of $(X,\tau)$ onto an open subset of $(Y,\tau_1)$.

I did write a proof for this but I have some questions about the validity of my proof. This is what I did:

---

#### My proof:

Let $\mathcal B$ be a basis for $(X,\tau)$. Then if we prove that $\forall B \in \mathcal B, f(B) \in \tau_1$, we prove the statement, because, $\forall A \in \tau, f(A)=\bigcup_i f(B_i)$, for some $B_i \in \mathcal B$, and if every $f(B_i)$ is opened, then $\bigcup_i f(B_i)=f(A)$ is also opened.

So, let $x \in X$, and let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $x$.

Then we have that $f|_U:U\to f(U)$ is an homeomorphism, because $X$ is locally homeomorphic to $Y$.

We can define a basis for $U$ as following: $\mathcal B_U=\{B\cap U,B\in \mathcal B\}$, as $U$ is a subspace of $X$.

We have that each $B \in \mathcal B_U$ is opened in $U$. This means that $f|_U(B)$ is opened in $f(U)$.

As $B \in \mathcal B_U$, we know that $B= B^*\cap U$, for some $B^* \in \mathcal B$

So $f|_U(B^* \cap U)$ is opened in $f(U)$. We have that $f|_U(B^* \cap U)=f(B^*) \cap f(U)$.

So we have that $f(B^*) \cap f(U)$ is opened in $f(U)$.Because f(U) is a subspace if $Y$, then this means that $f(B^*)$ is opened in $Y$, hence $f(B^*)\cap f(U)$ is opened in $f(U)$.  **(1)**

And this concludes the proof, if $B \in \mathcal B$, then $f(B)$ is opened.

---

So, the part of my proof that make me question whether it is correct or not is the step with the **(1)**. I'm not sure if that is allays true or not. If you spot any other mistakes on the proof aside from **(1)** please let me know as well.

Comment: sets are "open" not "opened" (abierto/ aberto/ ouvert might lead to confusion if coming from Romance languages..).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply take $U$ to be any open nbhd of $x$: all we know is that $x$ has **some** open nbhd $U$ such that $f\upharpoonright U$ is a homeomorphism of $U$ onto an open subset of $Y$.

Later on you say that $(f\upharpoonright U)[B^*\cap U]=f[B^*]\cap f[U]$; this needs more justification. You know that $f\upharpoonright U$ is injective, so you know that

$$(f\upharpoonright U)[B^*\cap U]=(f\upharpoonright U)[B^*]\cap (f\upharpoonright U)[U]\,,$$

but you don’t know that $f[B^*]=(f\upharpoonright U)[B^*]$: there might be some $x\in B^*$ and $y\in X\setminus U$ such that $f(y)=f(x)$. And in any case, the fact that $f[U]$ is a subspace of $Y$ is not enough to ensure that $f[B^*]\cap f[U]$ is open in $Y$: you need the fact that $f[U]$ is an **open** subset of $Y$.

You can simplify things and avoid these difficulties as follows. For each $x\in X$ let $U_x$ be an open nbhd of $x$ such that $f\upharpoonright U_x$ is a homeomorphism of $U_x$ onto an open subset of $Y$. Let $\mathscr{B}_0=\{B\in\mathscr{B}:B\subseteq U_x\text{ for some }x\in X\}$. Show that $\mathscr{B}_0$ is still a base for $X$. Let $B\in\mathscr{B}_0$; there is an $x\in X$ such that $B\subseteq U_x$. Now show that $f[B]=(f\upharpoonright U_x)[B]$ is open in $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

The following approach seems direct and straightforward from the definitions:

Let $O$ be open in $X$, and suppose $y \in f[O]$. Write $y=f(x)$ for some $x \in O$ and let $U_x$ be an open neighbourhood of $x$ such that $f\restriction_{U_x}: U_x \to f[U_x]$ is a homeomorphism between these open sets $U_x$ and $f[U_x]$ (definition of a local homeomorphism).

Then $U_x \cap O$ contains $x$ and is an open subset of $U_x$ so $f[U_x \cap O] \ni y$ is open in $f[U_x]$ (as homeomorphisms are open maps) and so open in $Y$ too, and a subset of $f[O]$, clearly. This shows that $y \in \operatorname{int}(f[O])$ and as $y$ was arbitrary, $f[O]$ is open in $Y$ as required.